# gimp text on a dial placed at specific locations (degrees)

Tags: text, geometry, drawing, clock, gimp

I have a (circular) dial. I would like to place text centered at a specific angle on the dial. A simple analogy would be a clock face with text above each hour mark. I can write text along an arc, placing text at the top (12h) position, then rotate that path to place it at a specific angle. The only solution I could think of was to create 1 layer for each text then rotate that layer appropriately (10 deg, 20 deg, 30 deg, etc.). This seems a brute force method, and I have not even been able to get it to work (yet). So, is there a better, standard way to do this?

TIA

ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely no standard way. But there are scripts that can make that easier. They can be found [here](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/) (some come with a self-contained doc, go directly to the [download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/).

- `dial-marks` will generate marks (with round sides if required). It's easy to remove the excess point to keep only arcs. You can have other uses for that one if you are in clocks.
- `ofn-path-edit` (`break apart` function) is used to make one path per stroke
- `text-along-path` can then be used to add text (centered) on each of these paths.

[Results of the three main steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Oc7H.png)

If you want to script this, plenty of code to borrow from in these scripts.

Comment: Looks like it should make life a little simpler for me. I finally got things installed, and will try it out later. Thx. +1 (PS (for Pretty Stupid): what do I do with the wire frame text? I really am a newbie with this:-))

Comment: `Select>From path` (or right click path in Paths list, and `Path to selection` and bucket-fill, usually.